# Popularity formula syntax error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out the syntax error in this code. I pulled a formula to use for popularity in my rails app from [here on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) and [here](http://popcornryan.tumblr.com/post/51194284106/hacker-news-popularity-algorithm-in-1-line-of-code). It's the same formula that [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) uses and it seems pretty straight forward. Yet I keep getting an error that I can seem to sort out.

```
@statuses = Status.select("statuses.*, (((statuses.cached_votes_total - 1) / POW(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popularity").order("popularity DESC")
```

Error Message:

```
  Status Load (73.1ms)  SELECT statuses.*, (((statuses.cached_votes_total - 1) / POW(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popularity FROM `statuses` ORDER BY popularity DESC
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popular' at line 1: SELECT statuses.*, (((statuses.cached_votes_total - 1) / POW(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popularity FROM `statuses`   ORDER BY popularity DESC
  Rendered statuses/index.html.erb within layouts/application (95.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 299ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popular' at line 1: SELECT statuses.*, (((statuses.cached_votes_total - 1) / POW(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now()-statuses.created_at)) / 3600)::integer + 2), 1.5))) AS popularity FROM `statuses`   ORDER BY popularity DESC):
```

I'm hoping that someone much better versed than I in MySQL and PG can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the hyperlinks are missing from where you describe the formula.   Also, are you after an answer for mysql or postgres?  The "::integer" syntax is postgres, but the error message is being reported by mysql

Comment: @Gary, thanks for pointing that out, it's been a long binge behind the screen! updated links.

Comment: @Gary, also I just recently switched my db to use pg for heroku so I'm fairly new to it (although I haven't noticed much difference), but this is what my console loads when I load `rails s` 
`Booting Puma`
`=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000`
`=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options`
`=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server`
`Puma 2.11.1 starting...`
`* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16`
`* Environment: development`
`* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the same query for both MySQL and PostgreSQL. The MySQL equivalent of `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (...))` is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...)`. You're gonna have to use two queries or write wrapper functions.